# Use shell to download multiple files from multiple links

Tags: terminal, command-line

I want to download multiple files from internet using `wget -P  /Users/<user>/Desktop/folder "link"`.
All the links have the form `"hello01world"`,`"hello02world"`,`"hello03world"` and so on

How can I write only one command line script that downloads all of them using for example a loop?
How do I modify the strings to get all links?

Comment: Use `wget -i urls.txt`, where `urls.txt` contains the URLs to download, one URL per line.

Comment: This also works but it's not exactly what I intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man wget` is a good place to start if you are unsure about the options a command supports:

- `wget -P /path/to/folder link1 link2 link3`
- Add all links to a file and then run `wget -i FILE -P /path/to/folder`

But if you want to auto-generate a link including numbers you may be better off using

- `wget -P /path/to/folder hello{00..99}world` (works in `bash` and `zsh`)
- `cd /path/to/folder; curl -O 'hello[00-99]world'`

Comment: Many thanks, this does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: wget being cross-platform, this can be used in Linux or Windows too, etc.